# Google map text size is small

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have major difference between google map on 4.4 and 4.1.2/4.3

In 4.4 all the elements(icons on map, cities names etc) look normal but in 4.1.2/4.3
they are seems to be like 40% smaller.

This is a web app with corodova/phonegap.

I added screenshot describing my problem, the are taken in a same location with a same zoom.

Ill be glad if someone can point me why this is so different between those android versions or any direction at all.

I have two major problems:

**1.The map is getting small with all elements.**

Map on 4.4

[image: map on 4.4]

Map on 4.1.2

[image: map on 4.1.2]

**2.places autocomplete results are also small.**

places autocomplete on 4.4

[image: places autocomplete on 4.4]

places autocomplete on 4.1.2

[image: places autocomplete on 4.1.2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many replies here i see....

The reason was the wrong parameters in meta tag that caused this strange behavior.